# Merge csv and json file in Leaflet map - strange mistake

Tags: r, maps, leaflet

Folks, I have no idea what a heck is going on. I did enough leaflet maps before and never had such problem. Shocked a little bit.
Doing very simple stuff.

**Cannot match [.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7e3vmhgp43s2sk3/US%20Adult%20Obesity.csv?dl=0) and [.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8q2se9w6zvm3r5/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json?dl=0) file by a state...**

```
# US Adult Obesity 2016

library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)
library(geojsonio)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)

# Set working directory
setwd("C:/~/App US Adult Obesity")

# Read csv
obesity <- read.csv("US Adult Obesity.csv", header = TRUE) 

# Read geojson file
states <- geojson_read("gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json", what = "sp")
View(states)

# Match data
obesity.map.2016 <- merge(states, obesity, by.x = "NAME", by.y = "State")
class(obesity.map.2016)
View(obesity.map.2016)

# Create a palette
obesity$Year.2016 <- as.numeric(as.character(obesity$Year.2016))
pal <- colorBin("Reds", c(22, 38), na.color = "#808080")
            #, alpha = FALSE, reverse = FALSE)


# Create a popup
state_popup <- paste0("<strong>State: </strong>", 
                  obesity$state, 
                  "<br><strong>% of adult obesity in 2016: </strong>", 
                  obesity$Year.2016)

# Create a map
leaflet(obesity.map.2016) %>% 
addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite) %>%  
setView(lng = -98.583, lat = 39.833, zoom = 4) %>%  
addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, 
          # opacity = 0.5, 
          fillOpacity = 0.7,
          fillColor = ~pal(obesity$Year.2016),
          popup = state_popup) %>%
addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = ~obesity$Year.2016, 
opacity = 1,
        title = "US Adult Obesity in 2016 by State")
```

[image]

As a result, I have Minnesota data in California. View shows that it does not match, I have 50 states + DC. 
I cannot believe that I forgot how to do it. 
Any hints about my stupid mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved personally. It looks like I screwed up with values, using them not from df, but from csv.

```
# US Adult Obesity 2016

library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)
library(geojsonio)

# Set working directory
setwd("C:/~US Adult Obesity")

# Read csv, which was created specifically 
obesity <- read.csv("US Adult Obesity.csv", header = TRUE) 

# Read geojson file
states <- geojson_read("gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json", what = "sp")
# View(states)

# Shape file - cb_2016_us_state_500k.shp
# states <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/DC/IFC/My Shiny apps/App US Adult Obesity", 
#                  layer = "cb_2016_us_state_500k", 
#                 encoding = "UTF-8", verbose = FALSE)

# Match data
obesity.map.2016 <- merge(states, obesity, by = "NAME")
class(obesity.map.2016)
View(obesity.map.2016)

# Create a palette
obesity.map.2016$Year.2016 <- as.numeric(as.character(obesity.map.2016 
$Year.2016))
pal <- colorBin("Reds", c(22, 38), na.color = "#808080")
            #, alpha = FALSE, reverse = FALSE)


# Create a popup
state_popup <- paste0("<strong>State: </strong>", 
                  obesity.map.2016$NAME, 
                  "<br><strong>% of adult obesity in 2016: </strong>", 
                  obesity.map.2016$Year.2016)

# Create a map
leaflet(obesity.map.2016) %>% 
addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite) %>%  
setView(lng = -98.583, lat = 39.833, zoom = 4) %>%  
addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, 
          # opacity = 0.5, 
          fillOpacity = 0.7,
          fillColor = ~pal(obesity.map.2016$Year.2016),
          popup = state_popup) %>%
addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = ~obesity.map.2016$Year.2016, 
        opacity = 1,
        title = "US Adult Obesity in 2016 by State (%)")
```